# interval of solution of a Linear Ordinary Differential Equation with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is
$$y'  + \frac{2ty}{t^2-4} = \frac{2t}{t^2-4}$$

with $y(0) = 1$ as initial condition. What is the solution and its interval?

Using some methods of solution I can come up with $y(t^2 - 4) = t^2 - 4$.
Considering that $y(t) = 1$, would that satisfy the equation for all $\mathbb{R}$?

Am I limiting the solution 'unnecessarily' if I choose $$y = \frac{t^2 - 4}{t^2 - 4}$$
since t can't be {-2, 2}?

And if the original differential equation was defined as $$(t^2 -4)y'  + 2ty = 2t$$

would $y = 1$ be valid for all $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a trick question. I agree with your answer: as stated, the equation does not make sense at $t=\pm 2$, and therefore there is no concept of its solution on an interval that contains $2$ or $-2$. The maximal interval of existence of the solution with $y(0)=1$ is the interval $(-2,2)$.

On the other hand, the equation $(t^2 -4)y'  + 2ty = 2t$ admits the solution $y(t)\equiv 1$ on the entire real line.